# Factoring out an exponential?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I have the following expression

$$\frac{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}{(k+1)^{k+1}}\cdot\frac{k^k}{2^k k!}$$

I get

$$\frac{2(k+1)(k^k)}{(k+1)^{k+1}}$$

But how do I factor out the ${(k+1)}^{k+1}$

Comment: Are you missing parentheses around the $k+1$?

Comment: You don’t, apart from cancelling one factor of $k+1$. What are you trying to do with this expression? Take its limit as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: yes I am trying to take the limit as k approach infinity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might help if you notice that $(k+1)^{k+1}=(k+1)^k(k+1)$.

Comment: how does such a factoring work I am wondering

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Think about what $a^k$ means. $a^2 = a \times a$, $a^3 = a \times a \times a$, etc. So $a^3 = a^2 \times a$.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez - It is the standard definition of exponents, i.e. $a^{b}\cdot a^c=a^{b+c}$. Therefore $a^k\cdot a=a^{k+1}$. Now let $a=k+1$ and we get: $(k+1)^k\cdot (k+1)=(k+1)^{k+1}$

Comment: I see yes it makes sense

Answer (score 6):

You have

$$\frac{2k^k(k+1)}{(k+1)^{k+1}}=\frac{2k^k}{(k+1)^k}=2\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^k=2\left(1-\frac1{k+1}\right)^k\;;$$

that last form should be easier to work with if you want the limit as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: I think $(\frac{k}{k+1})^k$ is $\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: So my limit would be 2/e

Comment: @Fernando: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{2^{k+1}(k+1)!}{(k+1)^{k+1}}\cdot\frac{k^k}{2^k k!}=$$
$$=\frac{2^{k}2(k+1)k!}{(k+1)^{k}(k+1)}\cdot\frac{k^k}{2^k k!}=$$

$$=\frac{2k^k}{(k+1)^k}=2\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^k$$